# Error installing Azure CLI on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, azure, ubuntu, linux-mint

I'm trying to install Azure CLI on Linux Mint 19. The official [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-apt?view=azure-cli-latest) states:

> This script is only verified for Ubuntu 16.04+ and Debian 8+. It may not work on other distributions. If you're using a derived distribution such as Linux Mint, follow the manual install instructions and perform any necessary troubleshooting.

I'm trying to follow those instructions, but at this line:

```
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl apt-transport-https lsb-release gnupg
```

I get the following error:

```
openssh-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

But I get this error in both cases:

```
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-09-16 22:39:42 -03; 6ms ago
  Process: 22323 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=255)
```

Comment: Do you run the update command before?

Comment: @CharlesXu yes, I didn't get errors at that stage

Comment: Maybe you can try to follow the steps just in [Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-linux?view=azure-cli-latest).

Comment: Does it solve the problem?

Comment: @CharlesXu Awesome! It does

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez Well, I will add an answer and you can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install the Azure CLI, you can choose the right steps for the special Linux distribution in the [Installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest). But when you do not find the steps for your Linux distribution, you can choose the [steps for all the Linux system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-linux?view=azure-cli-latest). But first, you need to meet the prerequisites.